# unity3d - How to disable buttons on GUI.Box when another GUI.Box is on top?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Here's the scenario.  I have a menu in the level that allows the user to pause the game.  When paused, a GUI.BeginGroup with GUI.Box has several buttons: resume, facebook, twitter, exit(then GUI.EndGroup()).  I show another GUI.Box on top of the pause menu when the Twitter button is tapped/selected.

Buttons on the pause menu are still active and I would like to disable them by either tossing up another GUI.Box before the twitter menu and just have it transparent?  Does anyone have any recommended solutions for this particluar scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. You can make the disabled buttons transparent then make them onclickable by using simple if else logic in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I created a bool pauseMenuButtonsDisabled = true and then just created the button just to displayed and if false had the button logic in place.